# Visual Studio code shows no longer threads in call stack

Tags: python, multithreading, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Time ago I used to debug applications that I made with QT designer, inside the application code I used qthread, those used to shown in the call stack window, but now I can no longer see them.

The call stack looks like this:

[image: Call stack image (now)]

and it used to show something like "Main Thread" or "Thread 1". I really need to use that information for my project. I tried search it in others discussions or in git hub issues but nothing like this, mi vs code version is 1.56.2

Comment: Can you provide a detailed picture, with this, we don't know the problem clearly.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?